# Fortran 90 to Fortran 2003 : pointer undefined reference

Tags: pointers, compiler-errors, fortran, undefined, fortran90

:)

Currently new to the Fortran language, I am currently on a question of migration from Fortran 90 to Fortran 2003, where a p1 pointer containing itself a p2 pointer generates the error message undefined when calling the ALLOCATE instruction reference for pointer p2.
The two pointers are declared as follows:
Within the struct_ames.f90 file:
`type(grid_ames), dimension(:), pointer::grids_ames=>null()`
Within the grid_ames.f90 file:
`CHARACTER(LEN=50),DIMENSION(:,:),pointer:: arrMeasurements=>null()`

Do you know how to solve this problem or which contact to request?

Thanking you for your attention to this request,

The code compiled fine with a version 13.1 compiler, but not with the new version 21 compiler.

The error message is:
`undefined reference to` grid_ames_mod_grid_ames_td_'`

Comment: For any concrete advice we will need to see a complete example ([mre]) and you will have to show how you are compiling.

Comment: Any source which has `type(grid_ames), dimension(:), pointer::grids_ames=>null()` is not Fortran 90 code, and most Fortran 90 source is Fortran 2003 source.